# How do I combine a copy of a signal with the original to achieve a chorus effect in a .wav file using Python?

Tags: convolution, python

Can you please explain or point the right way to think about how to implement two sound effects in a .wav file.

So I read a .wav file and converted it to int values (in `numpy` array)

```
array([59383, 58290, 60629, ..., 52606, 51982, 56274], dtype=uint16)
```

First, I am not sure I am clear about what these values in array really represent. 
Is it correct that every value is one out of 65535  ( `unsigned int16` ) magnitude levels that analog output device will produce in some moment in time?

In theory chorus effect could be achieved by following steps:

1. Make copy of original array
2. Weaken this copied array ( multiplying by some `value < 1` )
3. Add this copied array to original one

In practice I don't know how to add them correctly. Should I simply add values one by one, make a convolution of the two arrays or interleave original array and its modified copy?

Also a chorus effect should have an **arbitrary**  time **delay**  and I don't know how to accomplish this.

How could I implement that randomization of the time delay for the data I am about to add?